# Finding lowest value by shifting n numbers of datapoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
num
Out[89]: 
Date
2015-07-06    33
2015-07-07    20
2015-07-08     4
2015-07-09     3
2015-07-10     8
              ..
2020-06-29    14
2020-06-30    13
2020-07-01    18
2020-07-02    20
2020-07-03    28
Length: 1228, dtype: int64
```

I want to apply something like `num.lt(5)` on shifting basis every `n` days. Such as if it were able to find 5 but the day after there was a lower value of 4 and then 3, so on an interval of lets say 3 days it logs the value 3. So essentially what should happen is less than 5 but the minimum value lowest in the next 3 days. How can i do this?

For example :

```
 Date
    2015-07-06    33
    2015-07-07    20
    2015-07-08     4
    2015-07-09     3
    2015-07-10     8
```

On date `2015-07-08` it has a value of 4 which is true if I use `lt(5)` but the day after it has 3. I want it so that it logs 3 instead of both 4 and 3 because 3 is the lowest value. It should check on 3 days interval. Thus if it started to check for condition on `2015-07-08` it should check for the lowest value for the next 3 days which is till `2015-07-11`. Could you please advise this could be done?

Edit:

[image]
So wherever `lt(5)` is true will be the starting point and the next 3 days is where the lowest value needs to be found. The search for should only start at the end of the interval for the next starting point of `lt(5)`

Comment: Not sure to understand exactly, in the case of 2015-07-08, because it is a value under 5, you want to check within the next 3 days. And because there is a 3 in the next 3 days, that is smaller to 4, you want to replace the 4 by the 3? you want to do this only where the value at the origin is below 5 or you want to do this for all of the dates?

Comment: @Ben.T For value at origin which is below 5 only. Thus the minimum value which is found after `lt(5)` starting point.

Comment: After the starting point, do you want to find the lowest value of the next 3 days? Does it include the starting point which means 4 days from the point where you detect the value less than 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'number'],
    data=[['2020-01-01', 3],
          ['2020-01-02', 2],
          ['2020-01-03', 77],
          ['2020-01-04', 655],
          ['2020-01-05', 4],
          ['2020-01-06', 5],
          ['2020-01-07', 444],
          ['2020-01-08', 5],
          ['2020-01-09', 444],
          ['2020-01-10', 5],
          ['2020-01-11', 456],
          ['2020-01-12', 456],
          ['2020-01-13', 45],
          ['2020-01-14', 34],
          ['2020-01-15', 34],
          ['2020-01-16', 88],
          ['2020-01-17', 2]])

new_df = []
interval = 3
interval_temp = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1] <= 5 and index >= interval_temp:
        lowest = row[1]
        for i, row in df[index:index+interval+1].iterrows():
            if row[1] <= lowest:
                lowest_temp = [row[0], row[1]]
                lowest = row[1]
        new_df.append(lowest_temp)
        interval_temp = index + interval

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'number'], data= new_df)
```

output:

```
         date  number
0  2020-01-02       2
1  2020-01-05       4
2  2020-01-10       5
3  2020-01-17       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Date', 'X'],
    data=[['2015-07-06', 33],
          ['2015-07-07', 20],
          ['2015-07-08', 4],
          ['2015-07-09', 3],
          ['2015-07-10', 8]],
)
df = df.sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
df['rolling_min'] = df.X.rolling(window=3, min_periods=0).min().astype(int)
df = df.sort_values('Date', ascending=True)
```

returns

```
       Date   X  rolling_min
 2015-07-06  33            4
 2015-07-07  20            3
 2015-07-08   4            3
 2015-07-09   3            3
 2015-07-10   8            8
```

If you only want to modify dates with value < 5, you could use something like this:

```
df['X'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['X'] if x['X'] > 5 else x['rolling_min'], axis=1)
```

Comment: @kait Thank for your answer. On date ` 2015-07-09 ` 3 was reached, which was lower than 4 thus it will show only 3 and the date for that. The next lowest value will be in the next 3 days starting `2015-07-10 ` to `2015-07-13 ` and that will show the lowest value in that time interval.

Comment: Lower than 5 is the starting point but the lowest value in the next 3 days from the starting point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic you want. Can you post the desired output for the sample data?

Comment: I have added an image of what i am trying to do Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need the indices. Once you get those you can manipulate the data as you want.

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    "data":[3, 2, 77, 655, 4, 5, 444, 5, 444, 5, 456, 456, 45, 34, 34, 88]
})

a = 0
increment = 3
b = increment
l = []
while b<df.shape[0]:
    a = df.iloc[a:b, 0].idxmin() + 1
    
    l.append(a)
    b = a + increment 


print(l)

[2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13]  #for increment =3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {
    'date': pd.date_range('2015-07-06', periods=20, freq='D'),
    'value': [2, 3, 10, 20, 33, 20, 4, 3, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['log'] = df['value']

increment = 4
i = 0
while i < df.shape[0]:
    # Start find the lowest value in the range
    if df.loc[i, 'log'] < 5:
        # Find lowest the range
        lowest = df.loc[i, 'log']
        for j in range(1, increment):
            if df.loc[i+j, 'log'] > 5:
                break
            if lowest > df.loc[i+j, 'log']:
                lowest = df.loc[i+j, 'log']
        # Update value to the lowest value in the range
        df.loc[i, 'log'] = lowest
        for j in range(1, increment):
               if df.loc[i+j, 'log'] < 5:
                   df.loc[i+j, 'log'] = lowest
        i += increment
    else:
        i += 1
```

Output

```
         date  value  log
0  2015-07-06      2    2
1  2015-07-07      3    2
2  2015-07-08     10   10
3  2015-07-09     20   20
4  2015-07-10     33   33
5  2015-07-11     20   20
6  2015-07-12      4    3
7  2015-07-13      3    3
8  2015-07-14      8    8
9  2015-07-15      9    9
10 2015-07-16      2    1
11 2015-07-17      3    1
12 2015-07-18      4    1
13 2015-07-19      1    1
14 2015-07-20      4    4
15 2015-07-21      7    7
16 2015-07-22      4    4
17 2015-07-23      5    5
18 2015-07-24      7    7
19 2015-07-25     20   20
```